# multi level inheritance in C# without 'virtual' keyword

Tags: c#, oop

I'm new to C# , just a question on multi level inheritance
Let's say we have the following classes:

```
Class Employee
{
   public virtual void CalculateBonus() {
      ...
   }
}

class SalesPerson : Employee 
{
    public override void CalculateBonus() {
      ...
   }
}
```

let's say we have another class that derives from SalesPerson

```
class PTSalesPerson : SalesPerson
{
   public override void CalculateBonus() {
      ...
   }
}
```

so my questions is simple, the virtual keyword in the base class is needed to be overridable by its child class. Apply the same logic, the virtual keyword should also applying in the SalesPerson class as:

```
class SalesPerson : Employee 
{
   public virtual override void CalculateBonus() {
     ... //compiler error
   }
}
```

so that PTSalesPerson  can override its parent method.
so does mean that 'virtual' keyword needs to appear only in level 1 base class? or override = override + virtual?

Comment: Did you just try it both ways and see what happens? Well, yes you did and you got a compiler error. Why are you asking this question?

Comment: Once a method is declared virtual in a class, it will also implicitly be virtual in all its subclasses without reusing the keyword.

Comment: PTSalesPerson can already override CalculateBonus without any help.  It sounds a lot like you need a new method, not called CalculateBonus.  That new method can still call CalculateBonus, if appropriate, encapsulation is the other oop technique that is easy to overlook.  Calling that new method is not necessarily simple, the caller has to know that an Employee object is at least a SalesPerson.  The `is` operator helps with that.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot mark an *overriden* method as `virtual` as it is by definition already virtual

[virtual (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual)

> **Remarks**
>
> When a virtual method is invoked, the run-time type of the object is
>   checked for an overriding member. The overriding member in the most
>   derived class is called, which might be the original member, if no
>   derived class has overridden the member.
>
> By default, methods are non-virtual. You cannot override a non-virtual
>   method.
>
> **You cannot use the virtual modifier with the static, abstract, private, or override modifiers.**

---

If you do, you get a nasty compile time error

[Compiler Error CS0113](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0113)

> A member 'function' marked as override cannot be marked as new or
>   virtual
>
> It is mutually exclusive to mark a method with the new and override
>   keywords.

---

To answer the underlying concern, you mark the lowest level that needs to be *overriden* with `virtual`, any *derived* class then can `override` it

Comment: Just one thing is missing in this answer:  An overriding member is virtual by definition, therefor it's nonsensical to mark it as both override and virtual.

Answer (score 0):

The VIRTUAL keyword means that ANY child-level class CAN Override the given function.

So, if NONE of the child level classes have an override declaration of the function, they will all still have that function, it would just go to the top-most employee class.

If for example, you only did an override specifically to the PTSalesPerson class, then only THAT class would have the different functionality... The Employee and SalesPerson would still operate on the "Employee" level declaration of the function/method.

Does this help clarify for you?

Once any method is declared as virtual in its parent hierarchy, any child will ALWAYS be POSSIBLE to OVERRIDE from its parent regardless of the level.  But also, Lets say you have a hierarchy level

```
Class1
  Class2 : Class1
    Class3 : Class2
      Class4 : Class3
```

and you declare an override at Class3... Class4's instance will be operating based on IT's parent which is Class3's implementation of the method call, not Class1's declaration.

Now, if you want to do a combination, you can always call the base method, then do more.

Ex:

```
Class Employee
{
   public decimal MyBonus = 0.0m;
   public virtual void CalculateBonus() 
   {
      MyBonus = MySales * .13m;
   }
}

class SalesPerson : Employee 
{
}

class PTSalesPerson : SalesPerson
{
   public override void CalculateBonus() 
   {
      // go do the NORMAL Calculation at the EMPLOYEE Level
      base.CalculateBonus();
      // Now continue from that... As Part-Time sales person,
      // they get 1/4 of that rate.  So take whatever the result
      // WAS and multiply by .25
      MyBonus = MyBonus * .25m;
   }
}
```

**Clarification on calling chain of methods**

Per your comment/question, the method that PTSalesPerson would override would be Employees because that is the next declared method up the chain...  For a test, create your own classes like above and just do a MessageBox.Show("something") and see what happens on each.  If SalesPerson class had a declared method, then THAT would be the one overridden, but is also the "base.CalculateBonus" that is called.

Think of the "base." as family hierarchy.  You are child to your parents... Grand child to your grandparents.  So your "base." would be your direct parent.

**ADDITIONAL POINT on Inheritance**

One caveat I did not disclose (thanks Servy) is that of advanced class declarations where a class is marked as SEALED.  Sealed classes basically lock the class so no further derived classes can be done against it.  And that is applicable to the entire class... properties, methods, functionality, etc.

Comment: so what's method is PTSalesPerson overriding? SalesPerson's CalculateBonus() or Employee .CalculateBonus()?

Comment: @slowjams, added clarification at bottom of my answer, please review

Comment: "The VIRTUAL keyword means that ANY child-level class CAN Override the given function." That's not true.  A virtual method can also be sealed, preventing it from being overridden.

Comment: @Servy, yes, I agree, but we're going from someone just learning what a virtual vs override is,  Throwing sealed in will get into a new oohhhhhh moment.  Like anything.  If you have too much thrown at you, you can only absorb so much, you work, you learn, you get better and expand learning.

Comment: That someone doesn't know as much about the topic makes it *all the more important* to teach them accurate information, rather than giving them definitions that are just completely wrong.  Someone more knowledgeable could read your statement and not be confused or lead off track, because they'd know it's not true, but someone who doesn't know better is just going to be significantly harmed by being taught things that are just wrong, and will force them to have to unlearn what you've told them at some point in the future.

Comment: @Servy, understood... will add the context of SEALED classes to my answer, and sincerely appreciate your comments.